# Why does this script variable keep showing as "null"?

Tags: shell, variable-substitution, jenkins

I have the following script:

```bash
def String Service_version = sh "cd ./projects/onehome && pwd && cat package.json | grep version"
             echo "Service_Version_update: $Service_version"
             echo "My_Version is : ${Service_version}"
```

The output is:

```
cd ./projects/onehome
13:47:43  + pwd
13:47:43  /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/_apps_onehome_feature-AOTF-11540/projects/onehome
13:47:43  + cat package.json
13:47:43  + grep version
13:47:43  "version": "1.0.400",
13:47:43  [Pipeline] echo
13:47:43  Service_Version_update: null
13:47:43  [Pipeline] echo
13:47:43  My_Version is : null
```

Why is `${Service_version}` printed as `null`?

Answer (score 0):

Let's clean this up a bit:

```bash
## Ensure were in projects directory
cd projects/onehome/

## Switch to jenkins directory
$jenkins = pwd
$jenkins_output = "The current Jenkins Directory is: $jenkins"
echo $jenkins_output

## Create version Number
versionNumber = grep version package.json 
$serviceVersion = "The Current Service Version is: $versionNumber"
echo $serviceVersion
```

I believe you are trying to compare `myVersion` to `serviceVersion` to see if an update is needed.  With how I interpreted what you're meaning to do with your current code, your Service Version will ALWAYS equal My Version.   You may want to determine the myVersion with another approach.

Comment: how can I run all this wiring in one sh command?

Comment: Why does it have to be a fancy one-liner?  When using bash, variables don't need to be defined.   Run everything in a script.  See [LinuxConfig's Beginner Scripting](https://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial)